# Thread safety access to edit collection like BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I have multithread readers/writers that use shared collection.

```
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Execute(account));
}
```

in `Execute` Method I read `static Dictionary`, get first record where value is null and block it.

```
do
{
  if (collection.Any(x => x.Value == null))
      {
          var wall = collection.First(x => x.Value == null).Key;
          collection[wall] = 0; //block
          //Do something
          Console.Write(wall);
          collection[wall] = result;
      } 
} while (collection.Any(x => x.Value == null));
```

In result in console I get all walls that thread visited:

thread 1 : **A**BD**F**H

thread 2 : **A**CE**F**G

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548587/synchronized-collection-thread-safety), but BlockingCollection using to block unsafety `add` or `delete` element, how to thread-safety change collection?
I use .NET 4.0.

Comment: The Dictionary you use is not thread-safe without the *lock* keyword. If you want to use a BlockingCollection then consider putting the "walls" into it so the consumers each obtain a unique wall to work on.

Comment: You are overwriting the results as some of your threads in the same moment of time got exactly one `wall` number. You must sync your threads or refactor your logic.